# is there a web gui to import/export Rails I18n translations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, internationalization, translation

I use Rails 3 with i18n translations in the db

```
   create_table :translations do |t|
     t.string :locale
     t.string :key
     t.text   :value
     t.text   :interpolations
     t.boolean :is_proc, :default => false
   end
```

Is there a way to synchronize the development with the production db? or a webgui to import/export/edit the keys?

--
I meant something like http://drupal-translation.com/content/how-translate-interface-strings
Maybe It could be a rack gem with import/export/merge of yml files

Comment: HAve you tried writing a script to essentially do an export from one database to the other database?  If you're not using foreign keys, doing this type of import/export might be trivial for what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your looking for a database GUI.

- For sqlite, I recommend http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/
- For mysql, php my admin
- PostgreSql is shipped with pgAdmin
- For oracle, sqldeveloper

I'm not sure that's what you are looking for, and if the best solution with Rails. But these tools will help you manage your database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you are looking for but regarding importing/eporting yml files, there's a service called [GetLocalization.com](http://www.getlocalization.com) that allows you to do that so that they are easily editable by translators. There is also an In-page editor that allows you to edit strings on the web service itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could export your records to YAML and then load them.
Other option, if you are using the same type of database is to use the provided import/export mechanism (dump).

Answer (score 0):

We have built a service that focuses on exactly that issue: [PhraseApp](https://phraseapp.com).

It works excellent with Rails and allows you to edit/manage your translations within a browser interface.